# AWS service for backup Web and Database server. Launch a new environment from the disaster recovery backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

I am new in the AWS Cloud services.

I am doing the learning project to better understand AWS services.

I am assigned a project to prepare a new environment in the cloud, to which my team will later migrate their applications. The Stakeholders have come up with some Technical and Business requirements:

Disaster recovery plan: I need to have enough backups for both the Web and Database server so if in case the environment crashes, I can launch a new environment from the disaster recovery backups.

Which AWS Cloud service I could use to implement this requirement?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Backup a pretty obvious choice:   https://aws.amazon.com/backup/